# WPF textblock binding with List<string>

Tags: wpf, generics, text, binding

does anyone know if there is a simple way to bind a textblock to a List.
What I've done so far is create a listview and bind it to the List and then I have a template within the listview that uses a single textblock.

what I'd really like to do is just bind the List to a textblock and have it display all the lines.

In Winforms there was a "Lines" property that I could just throw the List into, but I'm not seeing it on the WPF textblock, or TextBox.

Any ideas?

did I miss something simple?

Here's the code

```
<UserControl x:Class="QSTClient.Infrastructure.Library.Views.WorkItemLogView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Width="500" Height="400">
<StackPanel>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Logs}" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Log Message">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

and the WorkItem Class

```
public class WorkItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CurrentLog { get; private set; }
    public string CurrentStatus { get; private set; }
    public WorkItemStatus Status { get; set; }
    public ThreadSafeObservableCollection<string> Logs{get;private set;}
```

I'm using Prism to create the control and put it into a WindowRegion

```
        WorkItemLogView newView = container.Resolve<WorkItemLogView>();
        newView.DataContext = workItem;
        regionManager.Regions["ShellWindowRegion"].Add(newView);
```

thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Convert your List to a single string with "\r\n" as the delimiter in between. and bind that to the TextBlock. Make sure that the TextBlock is not restricted with its height , so that it can grow based on the number of lines.
I would implement this as a Value Converter to XAML Binding which converts a List of strings to a single string with new line added in between

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Logs,Converter={StaticResource ListToStringConverter}}"/>
```

The ListToStringConverter would look like this:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(List<string>), typeof(string))]
public class ListToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(string))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a String");

        return String.Join(", ", ((List<string>)value).ToArray());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: One hint from the MSDN page: 'The data binding engine does not catch exceptions that are thrown by a user-supplied converter. Any exception that is thrown by the Convert method, or any uncaught exceptions that are thrown by methods that the Convert method calls, are treated as run-time errors. Handle anticipated problems by returning DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.' So it might be better to not throw exceptions in `Convert()` and `ConvertBack()`?

Answer (score 5):

if you use the converter it works for the first time perfect,
but if one or more logging comes to the logging list, there is no update on your binding, because the converter works only at the first time.
all controls that are no item controls doesn't subscribe to the listchanged event!

here is a little code for this scenario

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace BindListToTextBlock
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    private WorkItem workItem;

    public MainWindow() {
      this.WorkItems = new ObservableCollection<WorkItem>();
      this.DataContext = this;
      this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class WorkItem
    {
      public WorkItem() {
        this.Logs = new ObservableCollection<string>();
      }

      public string Name { get; set; }
      public ObservableCollection<string> Logs { get; private set; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<WorkItem> WorkItems { get; set; }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      this.workItem = new WorkItem() {Name = string.Format("new item at {0}", DateTime.Now)};
      this.workItem.Logs.Add("first log");
      this.WorkItems.Add(this.workItem);
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      if (this.workItem != null) {
        this.workItem.Logs.Add(string.Format("more log {0}", DateTime.Now));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the xaml

```
<Window x:Class="BindListToTextBlock.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:BindListToTextBlock="clr-namespace:BindListToTextBlock"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
      <BindListToTextBlock:ListToStringConverter x:Key="ListToStringConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0"
            Content="Add item..."
            Click="Button_Click" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1"
            Content="Add some log to last item"
            Click="Button_Click_1" />
    <ListView Grid.Row="2"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WorkItems}">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Name">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Log Message">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Logs, Converter={StaticResource ListToStringConverter}}" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

the converter

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace BindListToTextBlock
{
  public class ListToStringConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      if (value is IEnumerable) {
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ((IEnumerable)value).OfType<string>().ToArray());
      }
      return "no messages yet";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

here is a quick solution for the update propblem (this can be also made with a attached property)

```
public class CustomTextBlock : TextBlock, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ListToBindProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ListToBind", typeof(IBindingList), typeof(CustomTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(null, ListToBindPropertyChangedCallback));

  private static void ListToBindPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var customTextBlock = o as CustomTextBlock;
    if (customTextBlock != null && e.NewValue != e.OldValue) {
      var oldList = e.OldValue as IBindingList;
      if (oldList != null) {
        oldList.ListChanged -= customTextBlock.BindingListChanged;
      }
      var newList = e.NewValue as IBindingList;
      if (newList != null) {
        newList.ListChanged += customTextBlock.BindingListChanged;
      }
    }
  }

  private void BindingListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.RaisePropertyChanged("ListToBind");
  }

  public IBindingList ListToBind
  {
    get { return (IBindingList)this.GetValue(ListToBindProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(ListToBindProperty, value); }
  }

  private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
  {
    var eh = this.PropertyChanged;
    if (eh != null) {
      eh(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

here is the usage for the `CustomTextBlock` (not tested)

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ListToBind, RelativeSource=Self, Converter={StaticResource ListToStringConverter}}"
           ListToBind={Binding Path=Logs} />
```

@Fueled hope this helps

Comment: Is there a workaround for this? I'm having this exact problem in my log project.

Comment: Thanks, but I ended up using a MultiValueConverter and binding to the collection's Count property, which has for effect to update the Text property every time the collection is update. See my answer to another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353186/binding-observablecollection-to-a-textbox/8847910#8847910.

Comment: @Fueled oh i see, that's another solution for this problem, a little bit nicer than mine

Answer (score 2):

I'll shamelessly post a link to my answer of a very similar question: [Binding ObservableCollection<> to a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353186/binding-observablecollection-to-a-textbox/8847910#8847910).

Like punker76 said, if you bind your Text to a collection it will update when you set the collection, but not when the collection changes. This link demonstrates an alternative to punker76's solution (the trick is to multi-bind to the collection's count too).

Answer (score 0):

For concat collection of objects :

```
    /// <summary>Convertisseur pour concaténer des objets.</summary>
[ValueConversion(typeof(IEnumerable<object>), typeof(object))]
public class ConvListToString : IValueConverter {
    /// <summary>Convertisseur pour le Get.</summary>
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        return String.Join(", ", ((IEnumerable<object>)value).ToArray());
    }
    /// <summary>Convertisseur inverse, pour le Set (Binding).</summary>
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Juste think to overide the ToString() of your object.