# (Multi)Binding a List to a TextBlock in UWP or WinUI3

Tags: uwp, multibinding, winui-3

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353186/binding-observablecollection-to-a-textbox/8847910#8847910) would have been the answer but it only works in WPF. UWP and WinUI3 don't have Multibinding.

How do you make that code in UWP/WinUI3?

Comment: Can you give a scenario? x:Bind methods can take multiple parameters so could be used depending on what exactly you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8847910/6067603 The code in this post is exactly what I want to do. But I have no idea how to do that in UWP/WinUI3.

Answer (score 1):

> (Multi)Binding a List to a TextBlock in UWP or WinUI3

As Johnny Westlake said you could use x:bind method to binding a list to a `TextBlock`. For example, Use `String.Format` method to format list then render in the `TextBlock`. For more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/function-bindings#path-to-the-function).

```
<Page 
     xmlns:sys="using:System"
     xmlns:local="using:MyNamespace">
   <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">


 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind sys:String.Format(x:Null, '{0} is now available in {1}', FirstName, LastName)}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that sys:String.Format is winui3 with the UWP interface, but if you are using the newer winui3 "Microsoft:" (rather than "Windows:") Win App SDK interface, it is not supported. What is the best way to achieve equivalent under the newest interface, not the UWP interface?