# Bind a collection inside a collection in WPF combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

```
ObservableCollection<A> work = new ObservableCollection<A>();     
Class A
{
     int a;
     int b;
    observablecollection<string> c;
}
```

I need to bind" work" as the Itemsource of combobox and selectedItem as A. But I need to display the strings(c) of class A in the combobox. How will I display the strings C in the combobox. Any idea.?

Comment: Are you binding in XAML or Code-Behind?

Comment: does each item of the `ComboBox` have to show a list of strings?

Comment: Yes! that's my requirement.

Comment: similar issue as yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345385/wpf-textblock-binding-with-liststring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well if you need each `ComboBoxItem` to display a collection of strings, use an `ItemsControl` in the `ItemTemplate` of `ComboBox`.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding work}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock Text={Binding a} />
              <TextBlock Text={Binding b} />
              <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding c}" /> 
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```