# WPF Converting XML elements to DataGrid content

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid, valueconverter

EDIT: I'm open to another approach.  The source data is XML, but there's surely other ways to get the datagrid behaving.

[This answer got me started](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28619434/971583), but things seem to be different within a DataGrid.  The code works fine if I leave out the value converter, but if I put in the value converter, all I receive as input are empty strings.

Good but imperfect:

```
    <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Length" 
                Binding="{Binding XPath=length/@value}}" />
```

Junk:

```
    <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Length" 
                Binding="{Binding XPath=length, 
                          Converter={StaticResource valueFormattingConverter }}" />
```

I have a theory that the above is giving me the element content for element ./length (it's an empty element), but I actually want the element ./length because the attributes need to be processed.

Good but for combo boxes:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboButtonStyle}" Width="200" 
        Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource valueFormattingConverter }}"
          IsEditable="True" />
```

So with the Combo example, valueFormattingConverter.Convert gets called with an XmlElement (yay!).  With the DataGridTextColumn example, it's called with an empty string.

EDIT: ongoing research points to IMultiValueConverter as something I might want.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but is tedious.  I need to remake everything between DataGridTextColumn.Binding in every column, changing up each time the XPath.

If anybody can come up with a better way, the prize is open.

```
  <W3V:UnitsConverter x:Key="unitsConverter" />
```

...

```
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length">
      <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource unitsConverter}">
          <Binding XPath="length/@value"/>
          <Binding XPath="length/@type"/>
          <Binding XPath="length/@units"/>
        </MultiBinding>
      </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
```

...

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(XmlElement), typeof(string))]
public class UnitsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{

object IMultiValueConverter.Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, 
                   object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
  if (value == null) return new List<string>();

  string data = value[0] as string;
  string type = value[1] as string;
  string unit = value[2] as string;

  return Information.FormatValue(data, type, unit);

}
....
}
```