# Binding to TextBox only one-way

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I need to bind a `List<Key>` to `TextBox`. I've written a converter which converts from `List<Key>` to string (the `ConvertBack` method just throws an exception - it isn't used). Problem is that when I try to use this converter, it shows me an error: *The TypeConverter for "IValueConverter" does not support converting from a string.* It appears that the problem is caused because it's trying to convert `string` from `TextBox` to `List<Key>,` but I don't want to do that (user won't "write" to this `TextBox`). I've already thought about using something else than `TextBox` - perhaps `TextBlock` which I think would solve the problem, but I'd like to use `TextBox` for some other reasons.

My property I want to bind:

```
public partial class Settings : Window
{
    public List<Key> hotkeyCapture_keys { get; set; }
    ...
```

Converter:

```
class ListKeyToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Join(" + ", (List<Key>)value);
    }
    ...
```

And TextBox:

```
<TextBox ... Text="{Binding hotkeyCapture_keys, Converter=ListKeyToStringConverter}" />
```

When try to Build it, the app immediately shuts down with *"XamlParseException occured"*.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is really something you want to do.  If you want a read-only `TextBox` there are other ways of doing so out there already; one that you mentioned, another being `RichTextBox`.  But I'll assume you know what you want.

You'll first want to use this in your `Convert` (don't forget to add `using System.Linq;`):

```
return string.Join(" + ", ((List<Key>)value).Select(x=> x.Name)); 
//where Name is a public property in type Key
```

Secondly--bingo, [`TextBox.Text`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBox.cs.html#47e834d7646f17c6) binds `Mode=TwoWay` by default.  You can change that to `OneWay` or `OneTime`:

```
<TextBox ... Text="{Binding hotkeyCapture_keys, Mode=OneTime, Converter=ListKeyToStringConverter}" />
```

Also, you're throwing an exception.  Something has to handle that exception.  Nothing is.  Instead of throwing an exception in `ConvertBack`, just call `return null;`

Comment: Unfortunately the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

change your return value in converter to

```
 return String.Join(" + ", ((List<Key>)value).ToArray());
```

you can have a look at 
[WPF textblock binding with List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345385/wpf-textblock-binding-with-liststring)