# Binding all Texboxes in datagrid to list of string

Tags: wpf, datagrid

i would like binding all textboxes from datagrid to list of string. I do not know how to do it.
I have textboxes in one column of datagrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
  <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title}" Header="Title" IsReadOnly="True">
DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Width="60" Text="{Binding DataList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

In ViewModel:

```
    public ObservableCollection<DataObject> Data //datasource
    {
        get { return _data;}
        set { _data = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Data)); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> DataList //here must be data from textboxes
    {
        get { return _dataList; }
        set { _dataList = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DataList)); }
    }
```

For simplicity I did not write here call of command. In action method of command is DataList property still empty.

Thanks

Comment: You need to move `DataList` as `Data` of `Type`  `string` inside `DataObject`.  That's what the name `ViewModel` implies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:CollectionToStringConverter x:Key="CollectionToStringConverter"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Title" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.DataList,Converter={StaticResource CollectionToStringConverter},RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Write converter for converting collection of strings to one single string.

```
     [ValueConversion(typeof(List<string>), typeof(string))]
     public class CollectionToStringConverter : IValueConverter
     {

         public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
         {
             if (targetType != typeof(string))
                 throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a String");

             return String.Join(", ", ((IList<string>)value).ToArray());
         }

         public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
         {
             throw new NotImplementedException();
         }
     }
     }
```

Thanks to [WPF textblock binding with List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/345515/4112271)

Comment: Thanks. Just for clarification, this example join values from textboxes to list or from list to textboxes.. I need this:
TextBox1
TextBox2
TextBox3

and i would like binding values from Textboxes to list. Example of list:
List<string> data = new List<string>() {TextBox1Value,TextBox2Value,TextBox3Value}. each textbox will be one element in a list. Thanks