# How to join a List and bind it with a TextBlock in a GridView Block

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, data-binding, uwp

I want to join a list and bind them within a `TextBlock` in a `GridView` (or `ListView`) block.

Let me draw a picture to explain the scenario.

**C#**

I have a list of `StudentInfo` which contains **Name (`string`), ID (`int`) and Courses (`List<string`)**

**XAML**

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:StudentInfo">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind StudentName}" Margin="1"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ID}" Margin="1"/>
            <!--In the following textblock, I want to show something like this
                "Taken Courses Are - PHY, CHM, MAT"-->
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Courses}" Margin="1"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

In the last `TextBlock` I want to join all the courses a student have taken and show them with a hard coaded text -

"Taken Courses Are - ".

How can I do that?

Comment: Use converters to read values and format it as per your need.

Comment: Can you give a code sample, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF textblock binding with List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345385/wpf-textblock-binding-with-liststring)

Comment: Please visit the duplicate link and that has answer to your question

Comment: In the above link just change System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture. because is not for UWP. its for WPF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply use a IValueConverter to Bind list

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Courses,Converter={StaticResource ListToStringConverter}}" Margin="1"/>
```

Here the Converter

```
public class ListToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, string language)
    {    
        return String.Join(", ", ((List<string>)value).ToArray());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

## Edit

Add `ListToStringConverter` to your resources

```
<Page.Resources>
            <local:ListToStringConverter x:Name="ListToStringConverter" ></local:ListToStringConverter>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: Hi! Your code is throwing this --          #if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif

Comment: Well, I figured it out. This need to be added. <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:ListToStringConverter x:Key="ListToStringConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

Comment: I have modified

Answer (score 1):

Write a converter class to covert your list to a comma separated string.

XAML code

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Courses,Converter={StaticResource CourseToStringConverter}}" Margin="1"/>
```

CourseToStringConverter

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(List<string>), typeof(string))]
public class CourseToStringConverter: IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(string))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a String");

        return "Taken Courses Are - " + String.Join(", ", ((List<string>)value).ToArray());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture is not for UWP. its for WPF.

Comment: Thanks, I thought its for WPF, didn't find any where mentioned otherwise.